# Where should I install drain for RO system?

Tags: drain, kitchen-sink

Where should I install the drain pipe for an RO filter? I have heard that the drain pipe can get clogged if it’s directly after the disposal.

[image]

Comment: Yes it can get clogged. Open it from time to time and clean. If mounted top down less chance to get clogged.

Comment: Running extra water after you finish, especially with the insinkerator will help slow down clogging.  Also, I run a tub or two of hot water  once  week, to try and dissolve any build up of fats.